# Akka actorSelection vs actorOf Difference

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Is there a difference between these two? When I do:

```
context.actorSelection(actorNameString)
```

I get an ActorSelection reference which I can resolve using the resolveOne and I get back a Future[ActorRef]. But with an actorOf, I get an ActorRef immediately. Is there any other vital differences other than this?

What might be the use cases where in I would like to have the ActorRef wrapped in a Future?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**actorOf** is used to create **new actors** by supplying their Props objects.

**actorSelection** is a **"pointer" to a path in actor tree**. By using resolveOne you will get actorRef of already existing actor under that path - but that actorRef takes time to resolve, hence the Future.

Here's more detailed explanation:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/addressing.html

> An actor reference designates a single actor and the life-cycle of the reference matches that actor’s life-cycle; an actor path represents a name which may or may not be inhabited by an actor and the path itself does not have a life-cycle, it never becomes invalid. You can create an actor path without creating an actor, but you cannot create an actor reference without creating corresponding actor.

Comment: What is that actorRef does not exist when I do an actorSelection? Will a new one be created on the fly?

Comment: Call to context.actorSelection() does not create any actors - as the docs say: "No attempt is made to verify the existence of any part of the supplied path". When you call resolveOne on actorSelection pointing to non-existent actor, the resulting Future will be completed with ActorNotFound excpetion: [see more in docs](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.11/?_ga=1.195683951.2125247514.1432024129#akka.actor.ActorContext)

Comment: Thanks! that clarifies all my doubts!

Answer (score 0):

In either processes, there is an associated cost of producing an `ActorRef`. 
Creating user top level actors with `system.actorOf` cost a lot as it has to deal with error kernel initialization which also cost significantly. Creating `ActorRef` from child actor is very fair making it suitable for one actor per task design. If in an application, for every request, a new set of actors are created without cleanup, your app may run out of memory although akka actors are cheap. Another good is `actorOf` is immediate as you mentioned.

In abstract terms, `actorSelection` with `resolveOne` looks up the actor tree and produces an actorRef in a future as is not so immediate especially on remote systems. But it enforces re-usability. Futures abstract the waiting time of resolving an ActorRef.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brief summary of ActorOf vs. ActorSelection; I hope it helps:

https://getakka.net/articles/concepts/addressing.html

> Actor references may be looked up using the **ActorSystem.ActorSelection**
> method. The selection can be used for communicating with said actor
> and the actor corresponding to the selection is looked up when
> delivering each message.
>
> In addition to ActorSystem.actorSelection there is also
> **ActorContext.ActorSelection**, which is available inside any actor as
> Context.ActorSelection. This yields an actor selection much like its
> twin on ActorSystem, but instead of looking up the path starting from
> the root of the actor tree it starts out on the current actor.
>
> Summary: ActorOf vs. ActorSelection
>
> ActorOf only ever creates a new actor, and it creates it as a direct
> child of the context on which this method is invoked (which may be any
> actor or actor system). ActorSelection only ever looks up existing
> actors when messages are delivered, i.e. does not create actors, or
> verify existence of actors when the selection is created.